# Get changes for an item or a file (properties only)

Tags: power-automate

How can I loop thru all changed columns in a sharepoint list.

I use the

- TRIGGER "When a item or file is modified" and then the
- ACTION "Get changes for an item or a file (properties only)"

I thought I can loop thru the dynamic content "Column has changed" (A Collection showing which columns have changed)

But this is not a list of changed columns, this is a Object with all columns in the SP-List an a Status "true" or "false" if it is changed or not.

What I want to do, is to loop thru all changed columns and use SWITCH to define next steps per column.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no graceful way to do this as of now. However you can achieve this by keeping a reference of all your columns from SharePoint list.

Initialise an array variable `ColumnNames` and fill all your column names from SP list as it's input. I am taking top 4 columns from your setup. `ID, Title, Ticketno, Service_Type`

Initialise 2nd Array variable `ChangedColumns` to collect your changed column names. See the first image below.

[image]

Now use a for loop and iterate over `ColumnNames` and put a condition to check if current item (which will be the column name) value is `true` or not. If that's true then add it to `ChangedColumns` array, which we initialised to collect changed column names. The expression you need to use in condition is written as comments in the image itself.

[image]